# Optimal(fastest) trajectory between two points

Tags: algorithm

I would like to plan a route for a toy car on a plane (2d) with no obstecales. The toy car should move from point `(p1x,p1y)` to `(p2x,p2y)` (AKA Dirichlet boundary condition).Additional, that the toy car's speed at the starting point is `(v1x,v1y)`, and the required speed at the end point is `(v2x,v2y)`(AKA Neumann boundary condition).Lastly, the maximum allowed speed and acceleration are `vm` and `am` accordingly.

The goal is to find the fastest (which is not necessarily the shortest) course that connects the two points.

I've already tried several approaches: first of all I've defined the problem as a minimization problem with `K` points (`K` is an arbitrary number, say 100; there are `2K` unknowns). where each unknown is either the location or the delta in the location. Non of the minimizers I've tried where able to solve this task and all gave weird result for the most naive scenarios.

Any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would try first to solve it in 1 dimension (on a line) . I would use 3 types of acceleration (+am, 0, and -am ), and try to reach the vm limit when possible. You will have linear evolution of your speed. It will be easier to solve.

But the problem is that your speed vector is not always collinear. I would try to use Bezier curves for that.

Comment: Already tried. Problem begins when if one dimension arrives earlier than the other. The fast dimension It cant "wait" for the slow dimension, since the speed will be 0...
Since the two dimensions are dependent, I believe that in order to reach optimum the two dimensions should be solved together,

Comment: Perhaps with this keyword " trajectory planning using polynomial interpolations" you can find something usefull. This is not a trival problem.